# Finding a grammar for $L=\{a^nb^mc^rd^s| n+m<r+s\}$

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

I am trying to find a grammar for $L=\{a^nb^mc^rd^s| n+m<r+s\}$, which has the hint of it having "some similarity" to $L=\{a^ib^j|i<j\}$

This last one is quite easy to get ($S\to aSb | Sb | b$), but still I am unsure on how to proceed.

I expect to manipulate the language by differentiating cases, and for example I found that if $n>m$, I will have to solve $a^{m+k}b^mc^rd^s, k\ge1$, and if $n<m$, I will have to solve $a^nb^{n+k}c^rd^s, k\ge1$, but, still I don't see the recursivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any word $w$ in $L$ can be split into two words $w$ and $w'$ such that $w \in \{a^n b^m c^r d^s \mid n + m = r+ s \}$, $w' \in \{c^r d^s \mid r+s > 0\}$ and if the last symbol of $w$ exists and is $d$, then the first symbol of $w$ is $d$.
On the other hand, every choice of $w$ and $w'$ that satisfies the above constrains induces a word $w w' \in L$.

In the following grammar the first two productions take care of generating $w'$, while the other productions generate $w$. In particular the nonterminal $X_\alpha^\beta$ with $\alpha \in \{a,b\}$ and $\beta \in \{cd\}$ will generate all the words in $w \in \{a^n b^m c^r d^s \mid n + m = r+ s \}$ such that (i) if $\alpha=b$: then $n=0$ and (ii) if $\beta=c$ then $s=0$.

$$
\begin{align*}
S &\to Sd \mid X_a^dd \mid Yc \mid X_a^cc \\
Y &\to Yc \mid X_a^cc \\
X_a^d &\to aX_a^d d \mid X_a^c \mid X_b^d \\
X_a^c & \to aX_a^cc \mid X_b^c \\
X_b^d &\to b X_b^d d \mid X_b^c \\
X_b^c &\to bX_b^cc \mid \varepsilon
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Understood, that was a bit more complex than what I expected! Thanks!